# How can I call python funcitons with c++ in xcode?

Tags: python, c++

here is my code

```
#include <Python/Python.h>
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("print 1\n");
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

But something went wrong:
[image: info]

And `gcc my_python.c -o my_python -I/usr/include/python2.7/ -lpython2.7` is working well.Is it possible I try to call python in xcode?

Comment: Looks like you did not tell xcode to link against the python framework for your project.

Comment: @BarryScott I'm new about this.Can you show links?Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To use python in C++ in Xcode, you need to link the python framework to your .xcodeproj file.

Select your .xcodeproj file. Go to Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries and click the + icon.

[image: Image1]

You will be prompted to select a framework. Search for Python.framework and press Add.

[image: Image2]

Try building your project again and it should work.